# Replace text using Javascript on HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I have a php web page with many informations on it, some of them are quite sensitive and I would like hide them and the possibilty to unhide them.

My web page is built like this to show the informations :

```
echo '<b>Login :</b> ' . $data['Login'] . '<br \>';
echo '<b>MDP :</b>' . decrypt($data['MDP'], $passkey) . '';
```

So I'm working on a small Javascript code to hide/show the MDP. It's not finished (cause it work only half), it look like this :

```
<span class="visible">My text to hide</span><br \>
<span class="visible">My other text to hide</span><br \>

<button id="Replace" onclick="replace()">Change content</button>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById("Replace").addEventListener( 'click', replace);
}
var Visible = document.getElementsByClassName('visible');
var HiddenText = document.getElementsByClassName('hiddentext');
var OriginalText = new Array();
for (var k = 0; k< Visible.length; k++){
OriginalText[k] = Visible[k].innerHTML;
}

function replace() {
if (Visible != null){
for (var i = 0; i< Visible.length; i++){
Visible[i].innerHTML = '*****';
Visible[i].className = 'hiddentext';
}
}else{
for (var j = 0; j< HiddenText.length; j++){
HiddenText[j].innerHTML = OriginalText[j];
HiddenText[j].className = 'visible';
}
}
}
</script>
```

I don't know why it look like it only work once. It replace the text with the stars and the Class change well but when I use it again, nothing happen.

I tried the code separetely (both part of the if) and all work good.
I'm far from an expert to code so I probably missing something, maybe someone can help me on it.

Comment: I think `var Visible = document.getElementById('visible');` only gets one element-- you need to loop through all elements with that id, or, better still, use a class or something instead of an id. I believe ids are supposed to be unique.

Comment: maybe you should change the !== to != since you are not comparing 2 variables

Comment: Thanks for the advices, I changed the !== to != and use the class instead of the IDs and made some loop (I edit my post).
It still work half :'D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it in a different way, instead of replacing the text I just don't show it. I used PHP to hide the text, if you clic on the button the text is shown and after a delay a javascript code will redirect to the same page without the POST information that will automaticaly hide the text again.

```
function mdpviewer($data){
    $ShowMdp = false;
    if (isset($_POST['ShowMdp']) AND ($_POST['ShowMdp'] == true) AND ($ShowMdp != true)){
        $ShowMdp = $_POST['ShowMdp'];
    }else{
        $ShowMdp = false;
    }
    if ($ShowMdp == true) {
        return $data;
    }else{
        echo '';
    }
}

echo '<form action="MyPage.php" method="post"><input type="submit" value="Show Passwd"><input type=hidden name="ShowMdp" value="true"></form></div>';

echo'<p>My Password : (mdpviewer($data['Psswd'])</p>';

if (isset($_POST['ShowMdp']) AND ($_POST['ShowMdp'] == true)){
    echo '<script>setTimeout(function() {  window.location.href = "MyPage.php";}, 30000);</script>';
}
```

It's probably not optimized and a bit messy but it's working great !

If someone found how to do it with replacing the text on javascript I will be glad to see it

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could apply your logical differently. You could create php files whose purpose is returns data only in json format. This is simutale web service. So, when load page finished, by javascript you could request fetch to .php file endpoint, and manage response and make DOM modifications, another recommendation is you study es6 to do best practices! But is a tip, congratulations for resolve problem and my apologies if my english is bad, but im learning, cheers!